# Why is my HTML table extending to the bottom and right?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: It looks like this]

This is what it looks like, as you can see it's extending to the right and bottom. I'm trying to fix it but unable to. I am also using the bootstrap table class. Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>  
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="1"></td>
      <td class="2"></td>
      <td class="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="4"></td>
      <td class="5"></td>
      <td class="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="7"></td>
      <td class="8"></td>
      <td class="9"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width:500px; 
  height:500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 37.25%;
  top: 20%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border:2px solid #428bca;
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
}

tr {
  background-color:white;
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks for reading!
Edit:  This is what I want my table to look like:[image: pic]

Comment: What do you want to happen? I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: I dont want the table to extend to the right or bottom

Comment: This question needs a bit more information about the problem at you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you want to achieve try the following changes in your CSS

```
table
{
    height:800px;
    position: absolute;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td
{
    border:2px solid #428bca;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
}
tr
{
    background-color:white;
}
```

If you want your table to take the entire height of your screen at fit those boxes, You need to dynamically take height of the screen (through Javascript)

You can refer the following page for more details. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_height.asp

Cheers